# Will the depth of a file within a filesystem change the time taken to copy it?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I am trying to figure out if whether or not the depth of a file in a filesystem will change the amount of time it takes to execute a "cp" bash command with that file.

By depth I mean how many parent directories its contained in.

I tried running a few tests, but my results are pretty inconclusive, and when I try to logically answer, I can think of reasons of why it would be either way.

Comment: I can't think of any reasons why it would matter, unless the file system was implemented in a really inefficient way. Which brings us to the primary issue: there's no way to answer this question unless you specify a particular file system that you're interested in.

Comment: got it thanks! That's what I was thinking but then my results did have somewhat of an upward trend so I got confused, and I was able to rationalize it a bit.

Doesn't really matter for me though, I'm sure at least either windows or osx will be this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose of this?

Provided nothing is cached, the deeper the directory tree the more data has to be read from storage to get to the file - you have to find the name of the second dir, then the third within the second and so on. On the other hand if the file is big, the time needed to do this can be negligible in comparison.

Also mere startup of a command like cp is not without its cost.

If you are interested in how file systems work read this free book: http://www.nobius.org/~dbg/practical-file-system-design.pdf

Performance is a complicated subject, especially so when hard media is involved. **Without proper understanding of how this works and proper understanding of statistics, you can't perform a correct test.**

Comment: Thanks, it was just a conversation with a professor I had and he encouraged me to create a test, but I was having trouble creating a good test and analyzing my results since I haven't taken an OS class yet.

Really helpful answer though, thanks!